# Convert 4-dimensional image array into 3-dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to grab screen using MSS and pass it to a Yolov3 model detection. The problem is that the Yolo expects data to be in 3 dimensions and MSS grab method returns data in 4-dimensions. How can we convert the image data into 3-dimensions?

```
    import time
    import cv2
    import mss
    import numpy as np

    def main():
         mon = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 850, "height": 512}
         fps = 0
         sct = mss.mss()
         last_time = time.time()

         while True:
             img = np.asarray(sct.grab(mon))

             # here is something that I tried
             img= img.reshape(-2,512,850,1)

             #print(img.shape) #(512, 850, 4)
             #print('The Loop Took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
             last_time = time.time()
             cv2.imshow('CSGO', img)
             if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                 break

      return fps
```

Comment: Not sure about *"4 dimensions"*. Do you mean you want to discard the alpha/transparency channel, i.e. go from RGBA to RGB? If so, use `BGR = cv2.cvtColor(BGRA, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)` or somesuch.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, your comment is indeed the answer